# Cómo puedo hacer un conteo en el que si ya un cliente fue contado en un mes no lo cuente nuevamente en otro mes

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, numpy, data

Estoy trabajando con lo siguiente:

[image: Data]

En esta tabla podemos ver las variables, mes, id cliente, artículo, y precio neto Mes 1 es enero, 2 febrero y así sucesivamente. En principio quiero saber la cantidad de clientes que compran cada mes, para esto hago un conteo usando el Id cliente cómo base, dado que este es único para cada cliente. Lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
cuenta['Conteo']=1
cuenta=cuenta.groupby(by=['Mes', 'ID Cliente'],as_index=False).agg({'Conteo':pd.Series.sum})
cuenta['#Clientes/Mes']=1
cant_clientes_mes=cuenta.drop(['Conteo'],axis=1)
cant_clientes_mes=cant_clientes_mes.groupby(by=['Mes']
                               ,as_index=False).agg({'#Clientes/Mes':pd.Series.sum})
```

Esto produce esto

[image: conteo]

este #Cliente mes me dice cuántos clientes diferentes compraron en cada mes, sin embargo, quiero integrar que si alguno de los ID ya compró en un mes anterior, no lo cuente sino únicamente en el mes en el que aparece por primera vez, por ejemplo, el id 2122 compró en el mes de enero, pero también en el mes de febrero, quiero que la cuenta sólo aparezca en el mes de enero, de esta manera el mes de febrero sólo tendría dos clientes diferentes. Algo así, quiero que devuelva:

[image: Conteo Data]

Pensé en usar un for para meses y un condicional con <=, para el mes así:

```
for i in mes:
    for j in meses:
        if j<=i:
            cuenta=cuenta[cuenta['Mes']<=i]
            cant_clientes_mes=cuenta['ID Cliente'].unique().shape[0]
    print(cant_clientes_mes)
```

Pero el resultado es 5, 7, 8 en este caso me los acumula, no sé cómo hacer para que si ya lo ha contado en el mes anterior no lo cuente en el siguiente Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes obtener los valores que deseas utilizando el método `nunique()` ([documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html))

Tomando como ejemplo tu `dataframe`

```
    Mes ID Cliente  Articulo    Prc Neto
0   1   1225        TV          800
1   1   1225        Plancha     56
2   1   1222        Horno       120
3   1   1555        Play        500
4   1   1228        Sanduichera 20
5   1   2122        TV          900
6   2   2122        Play        500
7   2   2122        Horno       140
8   2   5664        Estufa      325
9   2   5666        Nevera      780
10  2   5666        Estufa      350
11  3   5666        TV          800
12  3   5666        PC          600
13  3   5666        Secadora    60
14  3   8222        TV          900
```

Primero, para obtener el número de clientes únicos por mes puedes hacer esto

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print(df.groupby('Mes')['ID Cliente'].nunique())
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Mes
1    5
2    3
3    2
Name: ID Cliente, dtype: int64
```

Para poder contar la primera vez que los clientes hacen una compra puedes primero eliminar los duplicados con el método `drop_duplicates` ([documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)) y luego utilizar el método `nunique()`

```
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID Cliente']).groupby('Mes')['ID Cliente'].nunique())
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Mes
1    5
2    2
3    1
Name: ID Cliente, dtype: int64
```